# `dotnet test` fails on a Maui project due to a dependency on Tizen

Tags: .net, maui

I am trying to run `dotnet test MyProject.UnitTests.csproj` on a Maui .NET 6 ("6.0.402" in global.json) project. I want to run this command in a pipeline on a hosted DevOps agent however I get the same error on my local dev machine.

When I run this command, I get this error message:

```
  Determining projects to restore...
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5): error NETSDK1147: To build this project, the following workloads must be installed: maui-tizen [C:\Projects\MyProject\tests\MyProject.UnitTests\MyProject.UnitTests.csproj]
C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\6.0.402\Sdks\Microsoft.NET.Sdk\targets\Microsoft.NET.Sdk.ImportWorkloads.targets(38,5): error NETSDK1147: To install these workloads, run the following command: dotnet workload restore [C:\Projects\MyProject\tests\MyProject.UnitTests\MyProject.UnitTests.csproj]
```

There is no Tizen folder or files under "Platforms" in my project. I'm using Visual Studio 2022 17.4.0.

There are no references to Tizen in the .csproj or any other files in the repo. I want to be able to test the app without installing a Tizen dependency. Searching online, I can see some references to earlier preview versions of .NET 6 Maui having errors related to workloads installed which is why I've pinned to a higher version.

Comment: I've never used dotnet test, but docs show a parameter `--os <OS>`. That should allow you to run test for a single platform.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve unfortunately no joy with that parameter. I think that is more about setting the platform of the test runner and really the tests should be running agnostic to platform (i.e. not trying to target Android/iOS/Tizen specifically).

Answer (score 1):

Could you share the project you tested for reproduction?

Basically, you can build and test .NET MAUI app without Tizen dependency if you do not install the Tizen workload manually.

As you can see below, when you create the .NET MAUI app (whether you're using Visual Studio Project Wizard or .NET CLI) you can see that Tizen TFM is annotated (by default) in project file (*.csproj).

```
<!-- Uncomment to also build the tizen app. You will need to install tizen by following this: https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET -->
<!-- <TargetFrameworks>$(TargetFrameworks);net6.0-tizen</TargetFrameworks> -->
```

If you need any help with Tizen .NET, please visit [Tizen .NET issue board](https://github.com/Samsung/Tizen.NET/issues).

Thanks,

Comment: I've created a reproduction project showing a project with no mention of Tizen failing the `dotnet test` command because of a requirement to have maui-tizen workload installed: https://github.com/BurkusCat/DotNetTestTizen

I've also reported this on the Maui GitHub: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/11579

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying with .Net 8.0 in mac, check Visual Studio -> Preferences -> Others (towards the Bottom) -> Preview Features -> Check Use .NET 8 SDK. Check all the options